# Any way to know when data is bound to select (dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cascadingdropdown

I'm looking for an eventhandler or a hack that can tell me when data is bound to a select or when the dropdown has been "filled" so to speak..

I have 3 cascading dropdowns. The first 2 filters data for the 3rd so to speak

***My question is***; is there any way to know when data has been bound to the 3rd dropdown? I'm using [this](http://www.dnasir.com/github/jquery-cascading-dropdown/demo.html) for my cascading dropdowns (if it helps)

The javascript in the link does provide an  onReady method, but for when all of my dropdowns are done initializing, the problem here is that I'm looking for the moment when Json has filled my dropdown with data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I `.promise()` you will read this https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Also seem to occur right before the data is actually bound - returns 1 when i .length my select

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering a custom event on data response:

```
$.getJSON('/api/storages', request, function(data) {
     $(document).trigger('dataBound');
     response($.map(data, function(item, index) {             
         return {
           label: item + ' GB',
           value: item,
           selected: index == 0 // set to true to mark it as the selected item
         };
     }));
});
```

And then listen to the custom event:

```
$(document).on('dataBound', function() {
    // Do your stuff...
});
```

Comment: This happens right before the population occurs - I tried returning amount of items in the select - always returns 1